# Getting the location of an element inside a scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok I've been looking at various solutions for the issue I am having but none seem to work for the issue I am facing. I have a Dev Express grid that is scrollable (which translates to a div as far as I can tell) Inside that grid I have some memo fields that I want to "pop out" in order to expand the size for typing without expanding the grid size and maintaining inline editing. What I have been trying to do is use JQuery to get the position of the cell within the grid to display the memofield at. This works fine unless someone has to scroll in the grid at which point the divs I have created popout at the position the control is on the page, not the position that the control is at within the grid. My question is how do I get the position that the grid has scrolled to? I have tried scrollTop and get nothing back. What am I missing?

CSS:

```
.memoField {
  height: 200px;
  width: 270px;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Javascript (so far):

```
function setPopUpLocation(o, parent) {
  var parentObj = $(o);
  var grid = $(parent);
  var pos = grid.position();

  posX = pos.left;
  posY = pos.top;
  if (editcontrol != null) {
    editcontrol.posX = pos.left;
    editcontrol.posY = pos.top;
    editcontrol.offsetTop = 0;
    editcontrol.style.display = 'initial';

  }
}

function showPopUp(s, e) {
  editcontrol = document.getElementById(s.name).parentElement;
  grid = document.getElementById("ASPxGridView1");
  setPopUpLocation(editcontrol, grid);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appeciated. I've also included an image of how the popout looks when the grid is scrolled. and how it looks (and should look) when it isn't. The behavior I am looking for is to have the "popout" appear at the location of the cell that was clicked in the grid relative to the current scroll position inside the grid.

[When Scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPDpa.png)

[Not Scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcWSn.png)

Comment: Where are the images that you have included. I cannot see any.

Comment: Could you provide some HTML code?

Comment: I will try and get some but dev express controls are horrible to navigate through and post HTML wise.

Comment: Just posted them. Forgot to add them initially.

Comment: What's the behavior you are looking for? You want the "pop out" to appear  where when "scrolled"? Or do you want the grid to "scroll back" to the element being "popped out"?

Comment: When I click on a cell in the grid (I have it set to an onclick event) I want the popout to appear on that cell. It works fine, so long as I have not scrolled within the grid.